# Ubuntu 14.04 on Mac using live USB gives corrupt display

Tags: system-installation, usb, mac

I have been trying to get Ubuntu to work on my desktop Macintosh running on OS X Yosemite but it doesn't seem to be starting up properly. I am using rEFInd to boot the USB, and I select Try Ubuntu without installing, and it all works up to now. As soon as the welcome screen pops up, I see four individual ubuntu screens. It also seem to be burning the pixels, and I cannot read the text on it.

Is there any way I can adapt the Ubuntu display for my mac?

I am using a desktop iMac (21.5-inch, from Late 2009). I am using a Mactel.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution to my problem, after trying various different ideas (booting from DVD, changing USB drive etc.)

I tried installing Ubuntu 15.04 instead of Ubuntu 14.04 onto the live USB. This finally worked!